# Apache TomEE vs JBoss EAP vs WildFly? OTMM

Tags: windows, jboss, installation, wildfly, apache-tomee

Im looking to install OpenText Media Management 16.2 on a Windows server. For the Application Server what is the most recommended Technology for a Windows 7 PC?

1. jBoss EAP 6.4
2. Wildfly 9.0.2 Final
3. Apache TomEE Plus 7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OTMM 16.2** is not supported for Windows 7. It is supported for windows 2012, Red hat linux and centos

Answer (score 0):

Once said OTMM is not supoprted by Windows SO desktops, only for servers Versions

I've worked with Jboss and TomEE, and of course Jboss is faster than TomEE at start app server.

Instead for developments deploy is more easy in TomEE.

About Installation I think it doesn't matter because in windows you have an installer